IgniteSpiException - BlT id of joining node (0) less than BlT id of cluster Error | Recovering
How to handle the below error, without losing the data in persistence?
Is there a file/directory in Ignite persistence directory for us to delete vs that of clearing the entire directory content?
Also is there a way we can backup and recover data from the persistence directory backup, when such a situation occurs?
To avoid:
IgniteSpiException: BaselineTopology of joining node () is not compatible with BaselineTopology in the cluster. BlT id of joining node (0) less than BlT id of cluster (5) but cluster's BaselineHistory doesn't contain branching point hash of joining node BlT (1538520902). Consider cleaning persistent storage of the node and adding it to the cluster again.
